# Remote debugging Mono application from Visual Studio 2015/2017

Tags: c#, mono

I want to remote debug a C# console application running on Linux from Visual Studio 2015/2017/2019. It seems I cannot find such tool to do this from Mono web site, can anyone confirm that Mono does not provide such tool to remote debug C# application running on Linux from Visual Studio 2015-2019? If that is the case, any suggestion on any tool that can do this? It is better that the tool can support Visual Studio 2015/2017/2019 and proved can work.

Answer (score 0):

Use vsMonoDebuger extension for visual studio. It can attach to mono process and deploy your program via SSH to linux. If you want debug already deployed app you nedd to start your app with mono with special arguments in command line. At arguments you can look in extension settings.